# User Input not printing, anyone know why?

Tags: c++

I am new to learning C++ and I'm learning from learncpp.com. I have just written a program that is meant to take user input in and print it out

Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter a number";
    system("color 04");

    int UserInput{ };
    int UserInput2{ };
    std::cin >> UserInput >> UserInput2;
    
    std::cout << "you entered: " << UserInput << "and " << UserInput2 << std::endl;
    
    Sleep(1500);
    system("CLS");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the input? what is output and expected output?

Comment: Enter a number: 4
You entered 4 
@463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69643001/edit) the question to add this information. Though it is not possible that you enter a single number and then get some output, because the program should wait for more input

Comment: There's no way that's the output you got. Post the exact input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press enter twice (fill in number, enter, fill in number, enter).

```
enter a number: 1
2
you entered: 1 and 2
```

Or separate the 2 numbers with a space and then press enter.

```
enter a number: 1 2
you entered: 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code in a way so that it is obvious for the user that an input is required (You're only aksing to "enter a number", although 2 are needed)  .  Apart from that, your code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Please add relevant code with your answer. Here is [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on SO.